# Website Freezing on IE9

Tags: javascript, web-services, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I am currently working on a website that uses SOAP to run numerous different wsdl web service calls. These calls are all made within an Account area that User must log into.

My issue is that ONLY on Internet Explorer 9, the site will completely freeze at seemingly random times. The only certainty is that it does not crash outside of this Account area.

There is not a single specific webservice call that causes the freeze, infact at various times each one has completed successfully on IE9, but at other times it wont.

I have checked through the whole site for console.logs that might have caused an issue, so none of them are evident. I have seen a similar question that links to AJAX requests, but this cannot be the case here. I have also seen a similar question that was fixed by turning off add-ons in IE settings, but I have tried this but to no avail.

Without attaching about 100 files I cant display any code, because it has frozen at so many different times/on different pages that there is nothing specific to show. I am hoping someone may have pointers on what may cause such a problem on IE9, and anything that is worth looking into that could be related.

Comment: Synchronous calls or large DOM redraws will cause it. Without seeing code, it is impossible to really help.

Comment: As stated I do appreciate that, but at this point I dont have some specific code that I know is related. I'm trying to get some ideas of why only IE9 would have this issue, so I can then narrow it down.